# Nativescript App keeps crashing with the following error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: nativescript

This app keeps crashing after about 10 minutes of non-use and the app remaining open. I'm new to Nativescript and don't have any idea where to start with this.

**--------- beginning of crash**

```
05-24 20:08:19.316 17271 17271 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadcab1 in tid 17271 (ivescript.PPMNS)
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'lge/g2_tmo_us/g2:5.0.2/LRX22G/1507914346dda:user/release-keys'
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : Revision: '10'
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : pid: 17271, tid: 17271, name: ivescript.PPMNS  >>> org.nativescript.PPMNS <<<
05-24 20:08:19.428   274   274 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadcab1
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     r0 a2dd9855  r1 a2dd9855  r2 00000000  r3 deadcab1
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     r4 9ecb52a0  r5 9ecb52d8  r6 af0e7000  r7 beef4564
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     r8 00000001  r9 00000000  sl 00000001  fp b4bb9ff8
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     ip a2efcef8  sp beef44b0  lr a2dd986f  pc a2dd9860  cpsr 60000030
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   : 
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #00 pc 006ca860  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #01 pc 006ca86d  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #02 pc 006ca8f1  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #03 pc 006c9e9b  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #04 pc 006c98bd  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #05 pc 006c9981  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.527   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #06 pc 006ca4b7  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (operator new(unsigned int)+78)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #07 pc 006ca4ff  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+2)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #08 pc 003360c0  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::HandleScope::Extend(v8::internal::Isolate*)+184)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0031aba4  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)+568)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0031af3c  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromOneByte(v8::internal::Vector<unsigned char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)+44)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0031b700  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)+480)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00279e5c  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int)+120)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #13 pc 00260101  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (tns::ConvertToV8String(std::string const&)+16)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #14 pc 00251195  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (tns::NativeScriptException::ReThrowToV8()+56)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #15 pc 00265381  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (tns::ObjectManager::OnGcFinishedStatic(v8::Isolate*, v8::GCType, v8::GCCallbackFlags)+200)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #16 pc 0033a55c  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Heap::CallGCEpilogueCallbacks(v8::GCType, v8::GCCallbackFlags)+120)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #17 pc 00349d2c  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags)+928)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #18 pc 00349ffc  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, char const*, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags)+152)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #19 pc 0034a32c  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Heap::CollectAllGarbage(int, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags)+68)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #20 pc 0027e004  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::Isolate::RequestGarbageCollectionForTesting(v8::Isolate::GarbageCollectionType)+64)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #21 pc 005971f4  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))+132)
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #22 pc 002ad5e4  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #23 pc 002ada34  /data/app/org.nativescript.PPMNS-1/lib/arm/libNativeScript.so
05-24 20:08:19.528   274   274 I DEBUG   :     #24 pc 00000090  <unknown>
05-24 20:08:20.772   801   817 I ActivityManager: Process gbis.gbandroid (pid 22408) has died
05-24 20:08:20.776   801   817 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service gbis.gbandroid/com.xone.internal.XoneService in 1000ms
05-24 20:08:20.776   801   817 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service gbis.gbandroid/com.cuebiq.cuebiqsdk.model.Collector in 242598ms
05-24 20:08:20.847   801   801 I BackupManagerService: Beginning scheduled full backup operation
05-24 20:08:20.857   801 22898 W BackupManagerService: Requested unavailable transport: com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
05-24 20:08:20.857   801 22898 W PFTBT   : Transport not present; full data backup not performed
05-24 20:08:20.872   801   864 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
05-24 20:08:20.894   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 org.nativescript.PPMNS/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-24 20:08:21.249   801  1151 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1afd861a u0 org.nativescript.PPMNS/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:833)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2830)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2687)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2531)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11795)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11667)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12376)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11887)
05-24 20:08:21.549   801 22897 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
05-24 20:08:21.585   801 22897 I ActivityManager: Start proc 22905:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/u0a69 for activity com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL
05-24 20:08:21.624   801  1203 D WifiService: New client listening to asynchronous messages
05-24 20:08:21.762   801  1898 I ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.PPMNS (pid 17271) has died
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the above happens both on a device and on Genymotion emulator.

Comment: NativeScript team member here. Please open an issue at https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues. Also a repro project would help us to investigate the issue further.